# Given an array of integers, output[i] = product of all elements besides itself

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this question has floated around StackOverflow many times before, but I'm trying to wrap my head around the **why** one solution in particular actually works. The question in full is:

*Given an array of integers, return an output array such that output[i] is equal to the product of all the elements in the array other than itself. (Solve this in O(n) without division)*

The solution I've come across in JavaScript is:

```
function productExceptSelf(numArray) { // sample input: [2, 2, 4, 1]
    var product = 1;
    var size = numArray.length;
    var result = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        result.push(product);
        product = product * numArray[x];
    }
    // result arr: [1, 2, 4, 16]

    product = 1;
    for (var i = size - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        result[i] = result[i] * product;
        product = product * numArray[i];
    }
    // result arr: [8, 8, 4, 16]

  return result;
}
```

I understand that in the first loop, the first 3 elements in the array are multiplied by the product (which pushes 1 the first time around, totaling 4 integers in the `result` array).

I'm not so sure I understand how looping backwards in the second loop and performing basically the same operation gives us the answer we're looking for. Is there a name for a method of this kind? I realize this is a strange question to ask, but bear with me please.

Comment: The first loop pushes the product on the left of each number, the second multiply that product with the rest of the numbers (on the right in the original array which explain why the loop starts from the end)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably illustrating the contents of the arrays at each pass through the loop would be helpful in understanding

```
// forwards loop through
x = 0:

product 1
result [1]
numArray[{2}, 2, 4, 1]
product after 2

x = 1

product 2
result [1, 2]
numArray[2, {2}, 4, 1]
product after 4

x = 2

product 4
result [1, 2, 4]
numArray[2, 2, {4}, 1]
product after 16

x = 3

product 16
result [1, 2, 4, 16]
numArray[2, 2, 4, {1}]
product after 16

Now the other direction
Product reset to 1

// backwards loop

i = 3
product 1
result before = [1, 2, 4, {16}]
result after = [1, 2, 4, {16}] -- (16 * 1) = 16
numArray[2, 2, 4, {1}]
product after 1 -- (1*1) = 1


i = 2
product 1
result before [1, 2, {4}, 16]
result after = [1, 2, {4}, 16] -- (4 * 1) = 4
numArray[2, 2, {4}, 1]
product after 4 -- (4*1) = 4

i = 1
product 4
result before [1, {2}, 4, 16]
result after = [1, {8}, 4, 16] -- (2 * 4) = 8
numArray[2, {2}, 4, 1]
product after 8 -- (4*2) = 8

i = 0
product 8
result before [{1}, 2, 4, 16]
result after = [{8}, 8, 4, 16] -- (1 * 8) = 8
numArray[{2}, 2, 4, 1]
product after 16 -- (8*2) = 16 (unused)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first loop multiplies each `output[i]` by each `numArray[j]` where j < i. The second multiplies each `output[i]` by each `numArray[j]` where j > i. The end result is multiplying each `output[i]` by each `numArray[j]` where j ≠ i.